# Can't deserialize Swagger OpenAPI tags as string array

Tags: c#, json, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I need to deserialize a collection of `OpenApiPathItem` from Swashbuckle generated JSON but the result is null collections within the object. I started tearing it apart to see what was tripping it up, and it is due to the Tags parameter within the Operation object.

The relevant JSON is

```
{
 "openapi": "3.0.1",
 "info": {
   "title": "MyApp",
   "version": "1.0"
},
 "paths": {
  "/api/v1/my-controller/{myParam}": {
    "get": {
      "tags": [
        "MyTag"
      ],
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "myParam",
          "in": "path",
          "required": true,
          "schema": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      ],
      "responses": {
        "200": {
          "description": "Success"
        }
     }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The problem arises from `tags` being a string array.

I get
**"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "MyTag" to type 'Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiTag'. Path 'tags[0]'"**

Here's my deserialization code so far (`swaggerJson` is the string of the entire document from /swagger/v1/swagger.json):

```
var convert = JObject.Parse(swaggerJson);
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> jToken in (JObject)convert["paths"])
{
    var operationObj = jToken.Value["get"].ToString();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenApiOperation>(operationObj, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
        });
}
```

And my Swagger middleware looks like this:
`builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen().AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();`

I don't see other people coming across this issue. There are many samples of Swagger JSON online where the tags are string arrays.

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Helen, I now know that OpenAPI's schema is not fully compatible with JSON and therefore Newtonsoft's deserializer cannot correctly convert the structure.
I have made a quick little workaround for my project that might help someone going forward.

```
internal class OpenApiPathItemOverride : OpenApiPathItem
{
    public new IDictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperationOverride> Operations { get; set; } = new Dictionary<OperationType, OpenApiOperationOverride>();
}

internal class OpenApiOperationOverride : OpenApiOperation
{
    public new IList<OpenApiTagOverride> Tags { get; set; } = new List<OpenApiTagOverride>();
}

internal class OpenApiTagOverride : OpenApiTag
{
    public OpenApiTagOverride(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public static implicit operator OpenApiTagOverride(string name) => new OpenApiTagOverride(name);

}
```

Use that in:

```
var convert = JObject.Parse(swaggerJson);
Dictionary<string, OpenApiOperationOverride> paths = new();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> jToken in (JObject)convert["paths"])
{
     var pathName = jToken.Key;
     OpenApiOperationOverride pathObj = null;
     Dictionary<string, OpenApiOperationOverride> operation = jToken.Value.ToObject<Dictionary<string, OpenApiOperationOverride>>();
}
```

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/issues/525#issuecomment-706718634) in the OpenAPI.NET issue tracker suggests using `OpenApiStringReader` instead of `JObject`. Does this help?

Comment: @Helen, yes that explains a lot! It's not truly compatible with JSON. Thank you. I have a partial solution to that. I'll add to my question with some info.